# How to use tkinter protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",function) with a function that runs twice?

Tags: python, tkinter, decorator

This is a function as part of a class to create tkinter Toplevel instances. I am trying to have the X button on each window destroy itself and then create two new windows. Every time I try running this, 'test' is only printed once and only 1 new window will appear. Why is this happening? Thanks!
Here is the class for creating tkinter instances

```
class App(Toplevel):
    nid = 0

    def __init__(self, master, title, f, nid):
        # Creates Toplevel to allow for sub-windows
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)

        self.thread = None
        self.f = f
        self.nid = nid
        self.master = master
        self.canvas = None
        self.img = None
        self.label = None
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry('300x300')

    def window(self):
        # Creates play_sound thread for self
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: play_sound())
        # Disables resizing
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.f)

        # Creates canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=300, height=300)
        self.canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor=NW, image=self.img)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    # Function to move each window to a random spot within the screen bounds
    def move(self):
        while True:
            new_x = random.randrange(0, x)
            new_y = random.randrange(0, y)
            cur_x = self.winfo_x()
            cur_y = self.winfo_y()
            dir_x = random.choice(['-', '+'])
            dir_y = random.choice(['-', '+'])
            # Tests if the chosen position is within the monitor
            try:
                if (eval(f'{cur_x}{dir_x}{new_x}') in range(0, x)
                        and eval(f'{cur_y}{dir_y}{new_y}') in range(0, y)):
                    break
            # Prevents crashing if the program happens to exceed the recursion limit
            except RecursionError:
                pass

        # Sets geometry to the new position
        self.geometry(f"+{new_x}+{new_y}")
        # Repeats every second
        self.after(1000, self.move)

    # Starts sound thread
    def sound(self):
        self.thread.start()

    # Changes the function of the X button
    def new_protocol(self, func):

        def run():

            @do_twice
            def cmd():
                print('test')
                func()

            def both():
                self.destroy()
                return cmd()

            self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', both)

        run()
```

Here is the function to create new windows

```
def create_window():
    global num
    # Hides root window
    root.withdraw()
    # Creates a new window with variable name root{num}.
    d['root{0}'.format(num)] = App(root, 'HE HE HE HA', r'build\king_image.png', 0)
    app_list.append(d['root{0}'.format(num)].winfo_id())
    print(d['root{0}'.format(num)])
    globals().update(d)
    # Starts necessary commands for window
    d['root{0}'.format(num)].window()
    d['root{0}'.format(num)].move()
    d['root{0}'.format(num)].new_protocol(create_window)
    d['root{0}'.format(num)].sound()
    d['root{0}'.format(num)].mainloop()
    num += 1
```

Here is the decorator function:

```
def do_twice(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

If anyone needs any other parts of my code I will gladly edit this to include them.

Comment: The simplest explanation would be that your `do_twice` decorator isn't working right - have you tested it on its own?

Comment: Yes I have, it does work.

Comment: Please show the definition of the `do_twice` decorator, and make sure your example is minimal, but complete.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ example. We need to see how you're creating the windows.

Comment: I'll do that, I just thought you meant a complete example of the decorator.

Comment: @TimRoberts That appears to be the problem, how would I rewrite this in a way that would avoid that then?

Comment: You need exactly ONE `mainloop` in your program.  All other windows will have their events managed through that main loop.  You can add other windows, but don't call `mainloop` again.  And don't abuse `globals` like that.  Just create a list or dictionary called `root`, and add elements there.

Comment: So I could just add a root.mainloop at the end of the program and it would work?

Comment: As long as a root window has been created, that's the way you should do it.

Comment: You've put too much code now. We only need enough code to reproduce the problem, and it doesn't sound like playing a sound is necessary.